# Can an animation trigger another animation in css3?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to trigger an animation with an another animation in CSS3 ? Or is it possible to make one  animation to start just after when an another animation is finished ? I know it is possible with java script,but i want to know if it can be achieved with pure css3 ?

Comment: set [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) for animation

Comment: Use the animationend event.

Comment: i don't want javascript to be included & animation-delay is based on time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) in conjunction with transition.

In my Snippet, the `transition` style causes `div` to change from:

1. Red to green in 1s.
2. 100px to 250px width in 2s.
3. 100px to 150px height in 1s.

The `transition-delay` style causes:

1. The first animation to occur immediately (background).
2. The second animation to occur after 1s (width).
3. The third animation to occur after 3s (height).

The end result is that each animation follows on the heels of the previous animation.

**Snippet**

```css
div {
  transition: background 1s, width 2s, height 1s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s, 3s;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:hover {
  background: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah.It works !But need some careful coding with the time.It would have been much better if there is a feature in which one animation will start automatically with the end of another one.

Comment: I'm fairly new to CSS3 animations, so if I discover a simpler solution, I'll post an update.